# Can someone explain this interesting git merging behaviour

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches,

```
A-C (master)
 \
  B-D (clean)
```

In `A..C` I added a directory with a bunch of files. In `A..B` I added the exact same directory and files, such that `git diff C..B` shows no changes in this directory. In `B..D` I did changes on those files. I want to merge those changes into `master`. I tried two different approaches, one worked cleanly and the other broke insanely badly:

```
git merge clean
```

The above command creates a tonne of conflicts, conflicts on every file in fact.

```
git merge clean^
git merge clean
```

The above works perfectly, merges recursively, no conflicts at all.

How and why does the above happen? Can git not look at the history and determine that it was an early split? Or would that be too potentially taxing to be used as a merge strategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, `git merge clean`, Git has no common ancestor for the conflicting files upon which to base the merges, so it looks like you are trying to bring together two trees that have both created the same filenames but with different content. (The common ancestor A does not have any of the files that are conflicting.)

In the second case, `git merge clean^ && git merge clean`, the first merge again sees no common ancestors, but is able to trivially resolve it, because the files are the same.  The second merge then can take the now-known ancestry, and just apply the diff.

Comment: git won't look at the history to find a known ancestry? (well, obviously not, but I'm curious why) Is it just that it could potentially take a long time to try to resolve it that way?

Comment: It does look at the history to find known ancestry. (See [git-merge-base(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html), for example.) However, the common ancestor of C and D does not contain any of the files that are modified in C and D and thus is of no help in resolving the conflicts.

Comment: @Matthew: The short answer is: it works well in practice. It's unusual to add the same files twice and with some differences in other files. A more common use case is cherry-pick, which git will detect and handle gracefully during a rebase. Although this would not solve your particular use case, git merge could certainly be improved to do the same thing rebase does. It should also be possible imitate darcs' merge, which I think should be able to handle this use case.

Comment: @drizzd: Yea, I'm aware it's unusual, but this is where I'm at because of a lack of forward thinking and public history. It just struck me as odd that I could do two merges and get perfect results, but a single merge would break. I've not played with cherry picking before, maybe I'll have a look into that.